# PDF Scraping Won't Load Text using PyPDF2

Tags: python, pypdf

I'm trying to pull all text from a list of PDF's but am running into errors when pulling the text from the object. Any idea what's causing this?

```
ls = os.listdir(resumes)
pdf = [s for s in ls if '.pdf' in s]
print(pdf)

for p in pdf:
    pdfFileObj = open(os.path.join(resumes, p), 'rb') 
    pdfReader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(pdfFileObj)
    print(pdfReader.numPages)
    pageObj = pdfReader.getPage(0) 
    print(pageObj.extractText()) 
    pdfFileObj.close()
```

Error:

```
  File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 19, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u0141' in position 305: character maps to <undefined>
```

Comment: Try using the encoding option at open: `open(os.path.join(resumes, p), 'rb', encoding='utf-8') `. Try other encodings until like 'latin1' until it works

Comment: ValueError: binary mode doesn't take an encoding argument

Answer (score -1):

Try this with pdfplumber :

```
import pdfplumber
import os 

resumes = "C:\\path\\to\\resumes\\"
ls = os.listdir(resumes)
pdf_files = [s for s in ls if '.pdf' in s]
alltext = ""

for pdf_file in pdf_files:
    pdf_path = resumes + pdf_file
    pdf = pdfplumber.open(pdf_path)
    nb_pages = len(pdf.pages)
    print(nb_pages)

    for n in range(0, nb_pages): # if you want to extract text from all the document
        p = pdf.pages[n]
        text = p.extract_text()

        if text is None:
            continue 

        alltext += text

    print(alltext) # This is will print all the text
    alltext = "" # reinitialize this variable
```